# Automake flex output naming

Tags: gnu, lex, automake

If if use, for example

foo_SOURCES = bar.l

then, automake generates via flex file `bar.c`. But, if I provide prefix `AM_LFLAGS=-Psome_prefix`, it generates `lex.some_prefix.c`, which is not known by other 
compilation rules, so it fails with `bar.c: No such file or directory`. Where is my mistake and how can I work around it? I really need prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way around this is to write your own rule for the .l->.c translation.  Something like:

```
x_SOURCES = lex.some_prefix.c
lex.some_prefix.c: lex.l
    ... rule here
```

You may also need a tweak to ensure you distribute the .l file.