# How to get automake to recognize the non-default filename produced by flex when %option prefix= is set

Tags: flex-lexer, automake

In general, automake's capability to properly invoke flex and bison when building parsers and scanners is incredibly useful.  However, I'm running up against an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I have a lex file, trigraphs.l, which performs the text replacement of C trigraph sequences.  There will be multiple lexers included in the final executable, which will be a pre-preprocessor that prepares the source file for the C preprocessor proper, so a subsequent lexer will take care of joining logical lines that span multiple physical lines, another one will strip out comments, etc.  Per the C standard, there is a specific order these transformations are supposed to take place in, so to avoid issues I'm using three separate lexers that will run in the proper sequence.

Anyway, to avoid symbol name conflicts I'm using %option prefix="blah," so my trigraph scanner is as follows:

```
%option noyywrap
%option prefix="trigraphs_"

%%

"??<"   { printf("{"); }
"??>"   { printf("}"); } 
"??("   { printf("["); } 
"??)"   { printf("]"); } 
"??="   { printf("#"); } 
"??/"   { printf("\\"); } 
"??'"   { printf("^"); } 
"??!"   { printf("|"); }
"??-"   { printf("~"); }
.       { printf("%c", *yytext); }

%%
```

The issue seems to be that automake->ylwrap is expecting an output from flex with the traditional lex.yy.c filename, to rename to trigraphs.c.  However, because the %option prefix also changes the output filename (to lex.trigraphs_.c), it doesn't get renamed to the trigraphs.c that the Makefile is expecting.  This causes the obvious compilation error when the Makefile wants to compile trigraphs.c and it doesn't exist.

One solution that occurred to me is to use %option outfile="lex.yy.c" to sidestep around that.  It seems to work so far; however, it feels a bit "hackish" so I wonder if there's a more idiomatic or canonical way to handle this.  When searching for solutions others had found, I did come across [this question on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569547/automake-flex-output-naming), but it's eight years old now so it's possible that there have been developments in the interim.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed in 8 years. Automake is just as quirky as ever, and while ylwrap really serves no useful purpose these days, it's still there and if you have multiple parsers or lexers, it will just get in your way. At least, that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more idiomatic way to handle this because Automake rules know nothing about flex.  Automake expects to work with project that are compatible with POSIX lex, and expects any lex implementation to follow the [POSIX convention of producing a lex.yy.c file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/lex.html#tag_20_65_12).